# Prevent EF Core From Updating A Column In A Specific Instance

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So I've seen the answer to this as being:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>(builder =>
{
    builder.Property(e => e.Prop7).Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
    builder.Property(e => e.Prop8).Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
    builder.Property(e => e.Prop9).Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
});
```

But how can I do this dynamically? How can I stop EF core from updating when I want it to, and allow it to update as usual the majority of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `PropertyEntry.IsModified` to `false` which will reset the property's value.

```
var myObject = ctx.MyObjects.First(); // e.g. myObject.Foo is "foo" in the database

myObject.Foo = "bar";

ctx.Entry(myObject).Property(o => o.Foo).IsModified = false;

// at this point, myObject.Foo is reset to "foo"
```